# Firebase signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult setup

Tags: firebase, apache, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, reverse-proxy

I have set up a reverse proxy from Firebase to my domain so I can signInWithRedirect on browsers that block third-party storage access. I host my Firebase app on my server and I dont use Firebase Hosting.

So now when I login with signInWithRedirect with Google Sign In, I now go to

`https://www.my-domain.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey={api}&redirectUrl=my-domain.com/login.html`

instead of

`https://my-domain-c64e1.firebaseapp.com`.

Which works and what their documentation says to do.

**The issue I'm having is that the page doesn't redirect back to where the user signed in.**

All I see is a Firebase page that says Site Not Found on it. The user stays on `https://www.my-domain.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey={api}&redirectUrl=my-domain.com/login.html`.

Is my reverse proxy in apache setup correctly to allow parameters in the url?

```
SSLProxyEngine On

<Location /__/auth>
    ProxyPass https://project-id.firebaseapp.com
    ProxyPassReverse https://project-id.firebaseapp.com
</Location>
```

Should my authDomain in my firebase config be set to `www.my-domain.com`?

Also, in my Google Cloud, my Authorized redirect URIs, is set to `https://www.my-domain.com/__/auth/handler`. Is this correct?

I can't figure out why its not redirecting back even though I have the proxy setup like they said.

Comment: yeah, indeed you have to set your `authDomain` to your custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

Posting Lafif Astahdziq answer in the comment as a community wiki for visibility.

Yes you should set your authDomain to your custom domain. You should check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices), it confirms here that setting your authDomain to your custom domain is correct, along with other best practices that you should follow.